# How to make a general reference to the primary key column in oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have multiple tables with a unique column name for each of their primary key such as: DeviceName, DeviceNumber, SwitchNumber, Etc.

There is another table which serves as an audit trail containing the changes from all tables, it lists the table name and the primary key value for each respective table as a reference i.e.

```
Table#2
TableName, InstanceNumber
```

I would like to use the information in table #2 to pull the respective records from each table in 'TableName' by referencing the 'InstanceNumber' attribute as the PK for each respective table without having to manually create a reference for each table's column name.

Is there a way I can do this? That is, create a query that references a 'general' column name to a table that points to the primary key column?

```
Select * from (TableName) where (PrimaryKeyColumn) = (InstanceNumber);
```

Comment: Nope, SQL is a highly structured language (the clue is in the name) and doesn't do "reflection", "generic names" or whatever. You could build such a statement in a stored procedure using Dynamic SQL and the data dictionary.

Comment: You can create a function that generates a query using oracle metadata tables to create a dynamic query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only do this using dynamic SQL -- in PL/SQL, that would be `execute immediate`.

Why not?  Here is one reason. All the columns returned by a query need to be known when the query is compiled.  That is, before any data is read.  You are requesting a set of columns that depends on the table that is in the data.  So, the columns are NOT known and the query cannot be compiled.